# unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data in express with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, express, fetch

I am working on a node API with React and Express. Node retrieves the data from Postgress like this:

```
router.get('/getRestaurants', async(req, res) => {
console.log('Restaurants');
try {
    const { rows } = await db.getAllRestaurants();
    console.log(rows);
    res.json(rows);
} catch(error) {
    console.error(`Error ${error}`);
    res.status(500).send({message: `API internal error`});
}});
```

The console.log it shows the data without problem and if I use Postman or Curl it seems to work fine. But when I try to retrieve the data from my frontend React I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

React makes the POST request like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch('http://172.20.0.4:3000/getRestaurants', {
            method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
            cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
            credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
            referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
            });
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data);
        return data;
    }
    fetchData();
});
```

It's probably not hard to see but there's something I'm missing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try deleting `mode: 'no-cors'`, and tell me if this worked for you.

Comment: If I delete the 'no-cors' mode I get these errors: 
```Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://172.20.0.3:3000/getRestaurants. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.```
The React app and the Api are in different docker containers and CORS does not allow to do that.

Comment: You need to allow CORS in Express API for your origin... then it will work. check this package, it might help you: [link](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)

Comment: It works!! With ```app.use(cors());``` in my index.js it seems to work like a charm. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem with CORS, since you are fetching data from another origin, you need to set `mode: 'cors'`, which means that you will fetch data across origins. when you set it to `mode: 'no-cors'` that mean that you don't allow cross origins and that is the cause of the problem. cos as you said. your express app has a different origin than your react app. but it will still not work until you allow your express api, the origin you are fetching from. by setting headers to: `ACCESS-CONTROLLE-ALLOW-ORIGIN *` and the star * means allow all kind of origins. but if you want to allow a specific origin, replace the
`*` with url of your react app. you can also use a node.js package that will help you at this in a clean and easy way, example using cors package https://github.com/expressjs/cors:

```
const cors = require("cors");
let whitelist = ["http://localhost:3000"];

// Middleware
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: function (origin, callback) {
            if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
            if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
                var message =
                    "The CORS policy for this origin doesnt " +
                    "allow access from the particular origin.";
                 return callback(new Error(message), false);

            }
            return callback(null, true);
        },
    })
);
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that it was a problem related to the CORS in the backend service. The link that you provided in the comment helped me a lot. Thank you for the explanation too.

Comment: Happy to help. the answer also explains how to allow specifics origins as whitelist. cos right now, you are allowing any origin to fetch the data from your api. Consider adding a whitelist.